# How is it better to install Open Social Distribution for Drupal in Container in Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker-compose, drupal, docker-desktop, opensocial

I am a beginner and need some help to find a good workflow for my task:
I need to try localy different  Drupal modules in frontend to understand if thay are useful for my future project (mostly in UX perspective) that will be probably done on the base Open Social Distribution for Drupal.
I have a Docker Desktop (on Windows via wsl2) and I want to install in container Open Social Distribution for Drupal (https://github.com/goalgorilla/drupal_social) with an additional module that does not belong to Open Social (https://www.drupal.org/project/student_registration). In future I want to add/delate other modules. I need to create image for open social each time I add/delate a module, is it so? Where can I find a template for a Docker file for this case?
Thanks a lot for your answer!

I installed Drupal from image that is situated in Docker Libraly in Container. IT works in Frontend (I can run it). I tried to install new modules in Folder "Modules" from Terminal with URL but it does not work. I tried to understand how to change Drupal image that I used but without sucsess.